Bridging the gap between Spring's JdbcTemplate and Kotlin coroutines
I'm learning about Kotlin coroutines. I'm wondering if I can use them to increase the throughput of my spring-boot application which is currently very heavily dependent on jdbc connections, without rewriting it to use a non-blocking database technology such as r2dbc.
Here is a greatly simplified version of the code I'm trying to refactor. You can assume that UserDao is using a JdbcTemplate to get data from a database. There are two methods, one which returns a single User and another which returns Stream<User>.
@RestController
class ExampleController(
    private val jdbcUserDao: UserDao,
) {

    @GetMapping("/user/{id}")
    fun getOne(@PathVariable("id") id: Int): User =
        jdbcUserDao.getUser(id)

    @GetMapping("/users/{ids}")
    fun getMany(@PathVariable("ids") ids: List<Int>): Stream<User> =
        jdbcUserDao.getUsers(ids)
}

I tried to rewrite this code so that it takes advantage of spring's coroutine support:
@RestController
class ExampleController(
    private val jdbcUserDao: UserDao,
    private val context: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO,
) {

    @GetMapping("/user/{id}")
    suspend fun getOne(@PathVariable("id") id: Int): User = 
        withContext(context) {
            jdbcUserDao.getUser(id)
        }

    @GetMapping("/users/{ids}")
    suspend fun getMany(@PathVariable("ids") ids: List<Int>): Flow<User> =
        withContext(context) {
            jdbcUserDao.getUsers(ids).consumeAsFlow()
        }
}

Would appreciate any comments on this refactored version. The code compiles and passes basic test cases, but I have a nagging feeling that I am not following coroutine best practices.

Welcome to Code review! The edit to make the post on-topic is appreciated. Hopefully helpful feedback will come soon.
